# Developing From PC To TI-83

Tags: embedded, basic

I'm playing with TI-83+ BASIC development. But I want to know if I can
write my code on the computer and compile it, then transfer the
program to the emulator.

Comment: +1 for creating the ti-83 tag.   =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can (if you buy one of [these kits](http://education.ti.com/educationportal/sites/US/productDetail/us_ti_connectivity_kit.html) -- they definitely used to sell them for the TI-83).

But do have a look at the feature sheet for the TI-connect software. It says `program editing` is Mac - only. Although (since it's a popular device) chances are you could find something homebrew on the net (if you're not on a Mac).

BTW: chances are very high that your BASIC does not get compiled but gets interpreted.

Comment: Probably true. I would guess that kit comes with an emulator so you can test things out on the computer, then transfer the code (i.e. the source, not compiled code) to your calculator where it looks the same as it would if you had written it on the calculator to begin with.

Comment: Doesn't the calculator come with one of those? I know mine did when I got one 6-7 years ago - and the same was the case for my TI-89, which is only 1½ years old. You shouldn't need that kit unless you lost the cable, or want a USB version. I'm also pretty sure that the CD was included, and that the software can be downloaded from their website...

Comment: @Michael Madsen: I remember having to buy mine in ?1997-1998? (I bought it at the time (in Europe) from a local Tandy (Radio Shack) shop).